# Retrieve contents of .txt file on web server without disturbing it?

Tags: c#

so i have a c# application which needs to use some code within a text file hosted on my web server (path: `https://example.com/example.txt`).

The contents of the text file contain some compiled code, heres a snippet of the compiled code:

```
 *ü
 *²0      ¾6-   +*
 +
 *²0      ¾6-   +S
 +;
 *²0      ¾6-   +y
 +`
 *²0      ¾6-   +Ÿ
 +‡
 *²0      ¾6-   +È
 +°
 *²0      ¾6-
 C
 *s0      µ6--.      y     +ð
 +Ù
*s0    ¾6-
    +ð
 +þ
 *s0      ¾6-
 ,   +ð
 ,
 *s0      ¾6-
 ¶   +ð
 ,
 *s0      ¾6-
 û   +ð
 , 
 *s0      ¾6-

   +ð
 ,/
 *s0      ¾6-
 C
 *W0      µ6-
 ,W   ,G
 ,>
```

In my c# application I've tried multiple ways of retrieving the contents from the text file on my web server in a way that wont mess up the compiled codes structure, such as:

```
string RetrieveText;
WebClient con = new WebClient();
RetrieveText = con.DownloadString("https://example.com/example.txt");
MessageBox.Show(RetrieveText);
```

The problem with this is that when my c# application is executed and the `MessageBox.Show()` pops up the compiled code gets a little 'un-organized' and some of the lines of compiled code located within the text file on my web server randomly get line breaks and spaces removed, for example when the compiled code shown above is retrieved using `DownloadString()` in the c# example shown above the `MessageBox` outputs this:

Same snippet of compiled code shown above but after i used c# to retrieve the contents of the text file hosted on my web server using `DownloadString()`

```
 *ü
 *²0      ¾6-   +* +
 *²0      ¾6-   +S   +;  *²0      ¾6-   +y
 +`  *²0      ¾6-   +Ÿ
 +‡  *²0      ¾6-   +È  +°  *²0      ¾6-
    *s0      µ6--.      y     +ð
 +Ù *s0    ¾6-     +ð
+þ  *s0      ¾6-  ,   +ð
,  *s0      ¾6-   ¶   +  ,   *s0      ¾6- +    ,   *s0      ¾6-
     +   ,/  *s0      ¾6    C
 *W0      µ6    ,W   ,G ,>
```

As you can see the compiled code has been changed from its original layout/structure, so basically my question is, is there a way to retrieve the contents from within a text file hosted on a web server using c#? And if so how could i retrieve the contents of the text file but without disturbing the layout/structure of the compiled code within the text file hosted on my web server?

I need to beable to use the contents of the text file on the webserver in my c# application like so:

```
this.CustomCONSOLE.SetMemory(566697660U, [HERE IS WERE I NEED TO PUT THE CONTENTS OF THE TEXT FILE ON MY WEB SERVER]);
```

Hopefully this question makes sense :/

Comment: @mikez Thanks! Worked perfectly :)

Comment: I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @mikez - You really shouldn't delete comments like that.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why not? The content was basically what's in my answer now. No real information was lost.

Comment: @mikez - I just makes the comments difficult to understand. The first comment now is "Thanks! Worked perfectly :)". I'd rather see the original comment plus the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use WebClient's `DownloadData` instead of `DownloadString`. `DownloadString` has to try and figure out the encoding and apply that to give you a string. You don't want that transformation done at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use DownloadString for complied string. This function design to use with normal string only. Use `DownloadData` instead.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

// Get binary data
byte[] downloadData = wc.DownloadData("https://example.com/example.txt");

// You can download your server file directly use download manager tools (etc. IDM) save it to "serverfile.bin" and compare it
byte[] orgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\serverfile.bin");

// using System.Linq;
bool isTwoFileEqual = downloadData.SequenceEqual(orgBytes);

// The result should be True
Console.WriteLine(isTwoFileEqual);
```